# Azure deployment script testing without deploying resources

Tags: azure, powershell, testing

Recently working on a large PowerShell script for Azure deployments. Is there a way to test the script without deploying the resources? Deployment takes a long time and so does cleanup. Whatif won't work as I am deploying with an input file and checking for resources created during deployment.

Comment: How about writing some unit tests with [Pester](https://pester.dev/)?  I used it just last week to test some Azure-related scripts and it worked like a charm. :-)

Comment: You can try to use `Test-AzResourceGroupDeployment`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell#test-template-deployments)